# Change to vertical text in label choropleth_mapbox Dash Plotly

Tags: plotly-dash

[image: choropleth_mapbox]

Hello. I need advice. How I can rotate my text in the *Label* from horizontal to vertical? Along the graph.

Comment: I found this one opportunity and it works `fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_title_side="right")`

Answer (score 0):

I found this one opportunity and it works `fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_title_side="right")`

[Magic underscore notation](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#magic-underscore-notation)